# How to find records with 2 not condition in rails where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table like this:

```
--------------------
| id | name | role |
--------------------
| ...| ...  | ...  |
--------------------
```

The role column has 3 kinds of role: Admin, Buyer, and User. With convention below:

```
role != 'buyer' and role != 'admin' ==> User is a normal user
```

( This means role can have value: nil, "", or manny different values, except 'buyer' and 'admin' )

```
role = 'buyer' ==> User is a buyer

role = 'admin' ==> User is an admin
```

Now, I want to find all the users in all 3 scenarios:

```
@admins = User.where(role: 'admin').all (work fine!)
@buyers = User.where(role: 'buyer').all (work fine!)
```

And all normal users, but this seems not working:

```
@users = User.where("role!='buyer' and role!='admin'").all (not working! )
```

Can anyone help me find all the normal users? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all rails version,

```
User.where('role NOT IN (?)', ['buyer', 'admin'])
```

If you are using rails >= 4,

```
User.where.not(role: ['buyer', 'admin'])
```

Comment: I finally found the problem, the problem is that when  the value of role column being nil, we cannot find that record. But when the value of role column other than nil, we can find it.

Comment: Emu's solution is not going to work if there are nil values because ```User.where.not(role: ['buyer', 'admin'])``` is equal to ```WHERE role != buyer AND role != admin```, and since ```NULL != any_string``` is falsy ```unknown``` any record with nil value won't be returned

Comment: @user3409950 I have to change my code a little bit to prevent nil value in role column, but anyway Emu's solution helped my code looks a little prettier :))